# Can a ventriloquist chant the Torah?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, torah-service, speech-talking

A [ventriloquist](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventriloquism) essentially recreates sounds using a different part of the speech system. For example, mouthing the sound ‘B’ would give away the act, so it must be recreated in a different part of the mouth.

Were one to read the Torah in such a manner, would the congregation fulfill their obligation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80565/discussion-on-question-by-shmuel-can-a-ventriloquist-chant-the-torah).